# Do I need to change the "aps-environment" string before exporting for app store

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, entitlements

since xcode 6? you need to add an aps-environment property in your entitlements file - this was automatically generated for me when I pressed the fix button.

Push notifications are working fine with an ad-hoc IPA,
 the value for aps-environment when I inspect the file is 'development'. Will this chage by itself when I Archive an app store release ipa ? or do I need to manually change the value of this string each time?

I can't find any info on this.

Comment: The environment is managed for you by Xcode, and you are actually using the production aps-environment when you build/export an ad-hoc build.   The best way to see this is whenever you archive the project, and press the button to upload to store there will be a window listing your  entitlements including your aps environment.

Comment: @JacobBoyd What if changes are made to dev backend and push notifications need to be tested on TestFlight? Backend is using Sandbox push certificates.